# How modify comment in PHPExcel?

Tags: excel, symfony, phpexcel

I'm working on PHPExcel Library on symfony!! I work on how to create a comment in a cell on my excel file. With the documentation I know how I can create a comment in mys excel file with this:

```
$objCommentRichText = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getComment('E5')->getText()->createTextRun('My first comment :)');
```

And it's work perfectly!! But now I try to modify the comment in cell E5 (who has comment "My first comment :)"). I just want to replace this comment by another one. I try something like that:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);//On lit le fichier avec la librairie excel
  $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);


  //$objCommentRichText = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getComment('E5')->getText()->createTextRun('My first comment :)');
  $objCommentRichText = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getComment('E5')->setText("My 2nd comment");//here I try to modify the comment

  $objCommentRichText->getFont()->setBold(true);

  $styleArray = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
        'name'  => 'Verdana'
    ));
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getStyle('E5')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

  $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, "Excel2007");
```

But it doesn't work :(. I try other but not work again... Someone can help me please ? Or have an idea to modify a comment ?? It will be great!

Answer (score 0):

```
$stringToBeReplaced = 'My first comment :)';
$objCommentRichText = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->getComment('E5')->getText();
foreach ($objCommentRichText->getRichTextElements() as $richTextRun) {
    $txt = $richTextRun->getText();
    if(strpos($txt, $stringToBeReplaced) !== false) {
        $richTextRun->setText(str_replace($stringToBeReplaced, "My 2nd comment", $txt);
        $richTextRun->getFont()->setBold(true);
    }
}
```

Didn't test code, but at least you can get the point...